# Should I try to minimize join with Spark Dataframe API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.5.1. with DataFrame API.

Given there are 4 DF (A, B, C, D) as input and I need to compute an output DF with 3 columns.
Column 1 computation uses A, B, C
Column 2 computation uses A, B, D
Column 3 computation uses B, C

I have 2 solutions :

1. avoid joining together A, B, C, D
2. joining together A, B, C, D

with 1. I'll write more code but I may hope performance gain (unless catalyst will do the job better than me).

What is the best option ?

Comment: There is not enough information here.

Comment: What is the missing information ?

Comment: If we don't know what are the solutions how can we suggest which one is better?